# Vector of vectors to array of arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a variable `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` I want to pass this variable to a function which accepts `array of array of float **float`. I was wondering if there is any way to do this?

Comment: Each vector should have raw pointer to its data `.data()` but without more information it is hard to tell

Comment: `array of array`, like a raw `float array[][];`?

Comment: If you already have a vector then you should stay away from the arrays and pointers.

Comment: Not a duplicate, in my opinion.  The dupe shows that a vector is an array, behind the scenes.  That doesn't work with a vector of vectors.

Comment: @Ron Legacy APIs, man!

Comment: @tadman Write a wrapper around old libraries.

Comment: @Drise True, but to do that you need to solve this conversion problem first, so we're right back to the original question.

Comment: Show us the signature of function in question.

Comment: You could try something like this: https://ideone.com/errhES